# "Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle distribution" error on new project creation on android studio

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, classcastexception

I have just downloaded android studio 3.4.2 onto this computer (Macbook Pro running OS X) and whenever I create a new project the gradle wont sync. and i get this error

```
ERROR: Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the 
specified Gradle distribution 
https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip'
```

After reviewing the log, I have narrowed the problem down to this (I think):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter 
cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.logging.Logger
at org.gradle.api.logging.Logging.getLogger(Logging.java:38)
```

All of the fixes I have found online also include a line in the log saying that there are multiple SLF4j bindings, yet my log doesn't say this and those solutions haven't worked for me. Please help

here is the log:

```
2019-07-29 19:43:59,511 [entQueue-0]   INFO - rd.FirstRunWizardFrameProvider - Overriding welcome frame to be resizable 
2019-07-29 19:44:05,113 [rImpl Pool]   WARN - ess.util.ProgressIndicatorBase - This progress indicator is indeterminate, this may lead to visual inconsistency. Please call setIndeterminate(false) before you start progress.
com.intellij.util.download.impl.FileDownloaderImpl$ConcurrentTasksProgressManager.updateFraction(FileDownloaderImpl.java:339) 
2019-07-29 19:44:09,987 [entQueue-0]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 159 project components initialized in 366 ms 
2019-07-29 19:44:09,987 [entQueue-0]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 0 module(s) loaded in 0 ms 
2019-07-29 19:44:10,231 [entQueue-0]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Subscribing project 'Project '/Applications/MyApplication' My Application' to indexing suspender events (com.android.tools.idea.project.IndexingSuspender@74c57e4b) 
2019-07-29 19:44:10,232 [entQueue-0]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender activation event: TEMPLATE_RENDERING_STARTED 
2019-07-29 19:44:10,232 [entQueue-0]   INFO - a.gradle.util.BatchUpdatesUtil - Starting batch update for project: Project '/Applications/MyApplication' My Application 
2019-07-29 19:44:10,801 [cessToken]]   WARN - BasedStripTrailingSpacesFilter - No current project is given, trailing spaces will be stripped later (postponed). File: /Applications/MyApplication/build.gradle 
2019-07-29 19:44:10,812 [cessToken]]   WARN - BasedStripTrailingSpacesFilter - No current project is given, trailing spaces will be stripped later (postponed). File: /Applications/MyApplication/gradle.properties 
2019-07-29 19:44:10,859 [cessToken]]   WARN - BasedStripTrailingSpacesFilter - No current project is given, trailing spaces will be stripped later (postponed). File: /Applications/MyApplication/local.properties 
2019-07-29 19:44:10,903 [cessToken]]   WARN - BasedStripTrailingSpacesFilter - No current project is given, trailing spaces will be stripped later (postponed). File: /Applications/MyApplication/settings.gradle 
2019-07-29 19:44:10,917 [cessToken]]   WARN - BasedStripTrailingSpacesFilter - No current project is given, trailing spaces will be stripped later (postponed). File: /Applications/MyApplication/app/build.gradle 
2019-07-29 19:44:11,288 [cessToken]]   WARN - BasedStripTrailingSpacesFilter - No current project is given, trailing spaces will be stripped later (postponed). File: /Applications/MyApplication/app/build.gradle 
2019-07-29 19:44:11,534 [cessToken]]   WARN - BasedStripTrailingSpacesFilter - No current project is given, trailing spaces will be stripped later (postponed). File: /Applications/MyApplication/app/build.gradle 
2019-07-29 19:44:11,538 [entQueue-0]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender deactivation event: TEMPLATE_RENDERING_FINISHED 
2019-07-29 19:44:11,538 [entQueue-0]   INFO - a.gradle.util.BatchUpdatesUtil - Finishing batch update for project: Project '/Applications/MyApplication' My Application 
2019-07-29 19:44:11,581 [entQueue-0]   INFO - util.EmbeddedDistributionPaths - Looking for embedded Gradle distribution at '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-5.1.1' 
2019-07-29 19:44:11,581 [entQueue-0]   INFO - util.EmbeddedDistributionPaths - Found embedded Gradle 5.1.1 
2019-07-29 19:44:11,765 [ thread 74]   INFO - ge.ExternalProjectsDataStorage - Loaded external projects data in 0 millis 
2019-07-29 19:44:11,780 [ thread 75]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 5ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2019-07-29 19:44:11,913 [ thread 74]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - CreateKotlinSdkActivity run in 147ms under project opening modal progress 
2019-07-29 19:44:11,932 [ thread 74]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Post-startup activities under progress took 171ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2019-07-29 19:44:12,075 [ thread 75]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update canceled 
2019-07-29 19:44:12,076 [entQueue-0]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
2019-07-29 19:44:12,085 [entQueue-0]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
2019-07-29 19:44:12,090 [entQueue-0]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
2019-07-29 19:44:12,095 [entQueue-0]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
2019-07-29 19:44:12,098 [entQueue-0]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender activation event: SYNC_TASK_CREATED 
2019-07-29 19:44:12,184 [entQueue-0]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - /Applications/MyApplication/.idea case-sensitivity: expected=false actual=false 
2019-07-29 19:44:12,184 [ thread 73]   INFO - pl.projectlevelman.NewMappings - VCS Root: [] - [<Project>] 
2019-07-29 19:44:12,200 [entQueue-0]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Started sync with Gradle for project 'My Application'. 
2019-07-29 19:44:12,201 [entQueue-0]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender activation event: SYNC_STARTED 
2019-07-29 19:44:12,201 [entQueue-0]   INFO - a.gradle.util.BatchUpdatesUtil - Starting batch update for project: Project '/Applications/MyApplication' My Application 
2019-07-29 19:44:12,248 [ thread 75]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 59 ms 
2019-07-29 19:44:12,296 [cessToken]]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
2019-07-29 19:44:12,302 [entQueue-0]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 3490 ms 
2019-07-29 19:44:12,303 [ thread 70]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home 
2019-07-29 19:44:12,304 [ thread 70]   INFO - oject.common.GradleInitScripts - init script file sync.java.lib contents "initscript {\n    dependencies {\n        classpath files(['/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/sdk-tools.jar', '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/sdk-tools.jar', '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar'])\n    }\n}\nallprojects {\n    apply plugin: com.android.java.model.builder.JavaLibraryPlugin\n}\n" 
2019-07-29 19:44:12,306 [ thread 70]   INFO - oject.common.GradleInitScripts - init script file sync.ng.build.script.classpath contents "import javax.inject.Inject\nimport     org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.ToolingModelBuilderRegistry\nimport org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.ToolingModelBuilder\ninitscript {\n  dependencies {\n      classpath files(['/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-extension-impl.jar', '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-extension-api.jar', '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-api-impldep-4.10.jar'])\n  }\n}\nallprojects {\n  apply plugin: BuildScriptClasspathModelBuilderPlugin\n}\nclass BuildScriptClasspathModelBuilder implements ToolingModelBuilder {\n  public     org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.builder.ModelBuildScriptClasspathBuilderImpl builder;\n  public BuildScriptClasspathModelBuilder() {\n    builder = new org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.builder.ModelBuildScriptClasspathBuilderImpl();\n  }\n  public boolean canBuild(String modelName) {\n    return builder.canBuild(modelName);\n  }\n  public Object buildAll(String modelName, Project project) {\n    return builder.buildAll(modelName, project);\n  }\n}\nclass BuildScriptClasspathModelBuilderPlugin implements Plugin<Project>{ \n  ToolingModelBuilderRegistry registry\n  @Inject BuildScriptClasspathModelBuilderPlugin(ToolingModelBuilderRegistry registry) {\n    this.registry = registry  }\n\n\n  void apply(Project project) {\n    registry.register(new BuildScriptClasspathModelBuilder())\n  }\n}" 
2019-07-29 19:44:12,755 [ thread 70]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed: org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.logging.Logger (555 ms) 
2019-07-29 19:44:12,756 [ thread 70]   WARN - ject.sync.ng.SyncResultHandler - Gradle sync failed 
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip'.
at             org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.DefaultToolingImplementationLoader.create(DefaultToolingImplementationLoader.java:114)
at     org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.CachingToolingImplementationLoader.create(CachingToolingImplementationLoader.java:44)
at     org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.create(SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.java:43)
at     org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.onStartAction(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:101)
at     org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:83)
at     org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
at     org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
at     org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
at     org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
at     org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at     org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultModelBuilder.get(DefaultModelBuilder.java:50)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.getBuildEnvironment(GradleExecutionHelper.java:567)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.prepare(GradleExecutionHelper.java:105)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.prepare(GradleExecutionHelper.java:94)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.SyncExecutor.executeFullSyncAndGenerateSources(SyncExecutor.java:281)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.SyncExecutor.syncProject(SyncExecutor.java:197)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.SyncExecutor.lambda$syncProject$1(SyncExecutor.java:137)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:217)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.SyncExecutor.syncProject(SyncExecutor.java:142)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.NewGradleSync.sync(NewGradleSync.java:197)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.NewGradleSync.access$000(NewGradleSync.java:70)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.NewGradleSync$2.run(NewGradleSync.java:163)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:727)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:164)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:582)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:532)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:87)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:151)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:403)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.DaemonRegistryServices$1.create(DaemonRegistryServices.java:59)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.DaemonRegistryServices$1.create(DaemonRegistryServices.java:57)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.CacheSupport.get(CacheSupport.java:25)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.CacheAccessSerializer$1.create(CacheAccessSerializer.java:33)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.Synchronizer.synchronize(Synchronizer.java:31)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.CacheAccessSerializer.get(CacheAccessSerializer.java:31)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.DaemonRegistryServices.createDaemonRegistry(DaemonRegistryServices.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
at org.gradle.internal.service.ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.invoke(ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.java:35)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:821)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:774)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:568)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:625)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:787)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:773)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:568)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:625)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:787)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:773)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:568)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:625)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:292)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:281)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:276)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConnectionScopeServices.createShutdownCoordinator(ConnectionScopeServices.java:61)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
at org.gradle.internal.service.ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.invoke(ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.java:35)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:821)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:774)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:568)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:625)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:787)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:773)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:568)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:625)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:292)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:281)
at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:276)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.initializeServices(DefaultConnection.java:123)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.configure(DefaultConnection.java:101)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractPost12ConsumerConnection.configure(AbstractPost12ConsumerConnection.java:37)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.DefaultToolingImplementationLoader.createConnection(DefaultToolingImplementationLoader.java:119)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.DefaultToolingImplementationLoader.create(DefaultToolingImplementationLoader.java:93)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.CachingToolingImplementationLoader.create(CachingToolingImplementationLoader.java:44)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.create(SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.java:43)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.onStartAction(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:101)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:83)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.logging.Logger
at org.gradle.api.logging.Logging.getLogger(Logging.java:38)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry.<clinit>(PersistentDaemonRegistry.java:50)
... 65 more
2019-07-29 19:44:12,787 [entQueue-0]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender deactivation event: SYNC_FINISHED 
2019-07-29 19:44:12,788 [entQueue-0]   INFO - a.gradle.util.BatchUpdatesUtil - Finishing batch update for project: Project '/Applications/MyApplication' My Application 
2019-07-29 19:44:12,790 [ thread 75]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols in FAST mode, 0 source files from total 0 project files 
2019-07-29 19:44:12,790 [ thread 75]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading symbols finished in 2 ms 
2019-07-29 19:44:12,790 [ thread 75]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading Header Maps finished in 0 ms 
2019-07-29 19:44:12,796 [ thread 72]   INFO - roid.tools.ndk.GradleWorkspace - Updating model took 0.001s 
2019-07-29 19:44:12,802 [ thread 75]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading Module Maps finished in 11 ms 
2019-07-29 19:44:12,802 [ thread 75]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving Module Maps finished in 0 ms 
2019-07-29 19:44:12,802 [ thread 75]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loaded 0 tables for 0 files (0 project files) 
2019-07-29 19:44:12,802 [ thread 75]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols for 0 source files 
2019-07-29 19:44:12,803 [ thread 75]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols for 0 unused headers 
2019-07-29 19:44:12,803 [ thread 75]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols finished in 1 ms 
2019-07-29 19:44:12,803 [ thread 75]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving modified symbols for 0 files (0 tables of total 0) 
2019-07-29 19:44:12,803 [ thread 75]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 0 ms 
2019-07-29 19:44:12,860 [ thread 75]   INFO - g.FileBasedIndexProjectHandler - Reindexing refreshed files: 47 to update, calculated in 2ms 
2019-07-29 19:44:12,990 [ thread 75]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Reindexing refreshed files took 130ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2019-07-29 19:44:12,991 [ thread 75]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 1ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2019-07-29 19:44:13,736 [ thread 75]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 745ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2019-07-29 19:44:13,737 [ thread 75]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update started: 19 files to update 
2019-07-29 19:44:13,773 [ thread 75]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Unindexed files update took 37ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2019-07-29 19:44:13,774 [ thread 75]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 0 ms 
2019-07-29 19:44:13,775 [ thread 75]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols in FAST mode, 0 source files from total 0 project files 
2019-07-29 19:44:13,775 [ thread 75]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading symbols finished in 1 ms 
2019-07-29 19:44:13,775 [ thread 75]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading Header Maps finished in 0 ms 
2019-07-29 19:44:13,776 [ thread 75]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading Module Maps finished in 0 ms 
2019-07-29 19:44:13,776 [ thread 75]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving Module Maps finished in 0 ms 
2019-07-29 19:44:13,776 [ thread 75]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loaded 0 tables for 0 files (0 project files) 
2019-07-29 19:44:13,776 [ thread 75]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols for 0 source files 
2019-07-29 19:44:13,777 [ thread 75]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols for 0 unused headers 
2019-07-29 19:44:13,778 [ thread 75]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols finished in 2 ms 
2019-07-29 19:44:13,778 [ thread 75]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving modified symbols for 0 files (0 tables of total 0) 
2019-07-29 19:44:13,778 [ thread 75]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 0 ms 
2019-07-29 19:44:13,837 [entQueue-0]   INFO - j.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider - 57 ms spent to cache options in project 
2019-07-29 19:44:13,956 [entQueue-0]   INFO - j.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider - 96 ms spent on EDT to cache options in project 
2019-07-29 19:44:14,324 [ thread 74]   WARN - WhatsNewAssistantBundleCreator - https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/assistant/3.4.2.xml 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/assistant/3.4.2.xml
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1872)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
at com.android.tools.idea.whatsnew.assistant.WhatsNewAssistantBundleCreator.downloadConfig(WhatsNewAssistantBundleCreator.java:221)
at com.android.tools.idea.whatsnew.assistant.WhatsNewAssistantBundleCreator.updateConfig(WhatsNewAssistantBundleCreator.java:209)
at com.android.tools.idea.whatsnew.assistant.WhatsNewAssistantBundleCreator.isNewConfigVersion(WhatsNewAssistantBundleCreator.java:133)
at com.android.tools.idea.whatsnew.assistant.WhatsNewAssistantCheckVersionTask.run(WhatsNewAssistantCheckVersionTask.kt:34)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:727)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:164)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:582)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:532)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:87)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:151)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:403)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2019-07-29 19:44:25,354 [entQueue-0]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
2019-07-29 19:44:25,444 [ thread 72]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 1ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2019-07-29 19:44:25,469 [ thread 72]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 24ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2019-07-29 19:44:25,469 [ thread 72]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update started: 9 files to update 
2019-07-29 19:44:25,491 [ thread 72]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Unindexed files update took 22ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your project then edit your project gradle, your version gradle is old, or your android studio is missing file. Download your android studio once more. Install Android Studio and make sure your Android Build 28.0.0 or more than it already installed